# Wrapping a Stored Procedure SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, procedure

using oracle to code the sql statement, been given some homework I don't thoroughly understand/struggling to grasp(so if you have any good tutorials/links for basic sql procedures/functions that would be appreciated.

### here is the question

A Stored Procedure that lists all names, descriptions and values of items in the La Trobe e-Auction database system together with a column which displays:
‘Sold’ if the auction is already closed and the item is sold
‘No bid’ if the auction is already closed and no bid has been placed for the item
‘No sale’ if the auction is already closed but the reserve price was not met

### ‘On auction’ if the auction for the item is still open

```
Item (itemNumber, itemName, itemDescription, itemValue, itemLocation, 
categoryID, sellerUsername)   

Auction (auctionNumber, currency, startDateTime, endDateTime, shippingTerms, 
startBidAmount, reserveAmount, bidIncrementAmount, noOfItems, itemSold, 
itemNumber feedbackDateAndTime, rating, comments, paymentDate, paymentid)

Bid (bidderUsername, auctionNumber, bidDateTime,bidAmount)
```

here is the theory I have worked out but I am at a loss on how to code it.

```
status column -  a)sold, closed and item is sold
                 b)no bid, auction is close and no bids
                 c)no sale, the auction is closed but reserve wasnt met
                 d)on auction, auction for the item is still open

                 a) if i.itemnumber=a.itemnumber and itemSold='y'
                 b) if a.auctionnumber != b.auctionnumber and systemdate>endDateTime
                 c) if sysdate>endDatetime and a.auctionnumber=b.auctionnumber 
                 and reserveamount>select b.bidAmount 
                 from bid where a.auctionnumber=b.auctionnumber 
                 and b.bidAmount.max;
                 d) if itemSold ='n' and sysdate<endDateTime;




CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE allItemStatus
AS 
    p_itemName Item.itemName%TYPE;
    p_itemDescription Item.itemDescription%TYPE;
    p_itemValue Item.itemValue%TYPE;
    P_itemSold Auction.itemSold%TYPE;
    BEGIN
SELECT i.itemName, i.itemDescription, i.itemValue, a.itemSold
INTO p_itemName, p_itemDescription, p_itemValue , p_itemSold
FROM dbf12.Item i, dbf12.Auction a
WHERE i.itemNumber=a.itemNumber 
AND a.itemSold='Y';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item Name: '||p_itemName);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item Description: '||p_itemDescription);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item Value: '||p_itemValue);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item Sold: '||p_itemSold);
    END allItemStatus;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I've barely written out the entire thing but I am not sure where to go with this.

here is my current code, it doesnt like my sysdate>a.enddattime

```
SELECT
   i.itemname,
   i.itemdescription,
   i.itemvalue,
   CASE
       WHEN i.itemnumber=a.itemnumber and a.itemSold='y' THEN 'Sold'
       WHEN a.auctionnumber != b.auctionnumber and systemdate>endDateTime THEN 'No Bids on that closed auction'
       WHEN TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')<a.endDatetime and a.auctionnumber=b.auctionnumber 
                 and reserveamount>(
                 SELECT b.bidAmount 
                 WHERE a.auctionnumber=b.auctionnumber 
                 AND b.bidAmount.max) THEN 'No Bids that meets the reserve'
        ELSE 'Auction Still Open'
   END 
FROM 
   dbf12.item i, dbf12.auction a, dbf12.bid b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE statement

```
SELECT
   itemname,
   itemdescription,
   itemvalue,
   CASE
       WHEN status=1 THEN 'Sold'
       WHEN status=2 THEN 'No Bid'
       WHEN status=3 AND (another condition here) THEN 'Closed'
       ELSE 'What Else'
   END display
FROM 
    eAuction
```

"display" is the name given to the column that displays "Sold" etc.

Comment: how would you set the conditions for status=1? for example make  if i.itemnumber=a.itemnumber and itemSold='y'. how would you put this into it

Comment: that was just a guide, you can replace those with appropriate conditions